# TeXLive getnonfreefonts-sys error: untrusted certificate from tug.org

Tags: texlive, installing-fonts

I recently installed TeXLive 2016 on a partition where I run Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 OS (Italy-localized). I am experiencing some problems with the installation of the additional fonts. Following the instructions I found in many sites, I downloaded and also successfully ran the appropriate script `install-getnonfreefonts`. Then I tried to execute `getnonfreefonts-sys -a` to get and install all the fonts but I received an error message telling that the SSL certificate issued by tug.org is not valid. This error prevented `wget.exe` to run and do the right job. A Google search shows that some time in the past a specific question about this problem had been posted here but the related thread is currently unavailable because that question (together with all its answers) has been removed. As it stands, I cannot tell whether it is an OS issue (I did not find anything useful on the web) or there may be something wrong with TeXLive. I succeeded in catching an image from my Windows console I got by trying to obtain a list of additional fonts:

[image: Error message]

As it can be easily noticed, error message comes with the exact IP address (and port number) of tug.org.

Comment: Exactly which URL is it that it does not trust? Please always cite the explicit error messages.

Comment: Strange because Firefox does trust it. Might be an idea to take it to the texlive list (I'm not sure of the developer read TSE)

Comment: I just tried updating `garamondx` that used to fail with this problem; now it works.

Comment: I am getting the same issue in Arch Linux, TexLive 2020:
```getnonfreefonts --sys -a

.
.
.
ERROR: El certificado de “www.tug.org” no es confiable.
ERROR: The certificate of “www.tug.org” doesn't have a known issuer.
! Error: Can't execute wget.
```
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621580/getnonfreefonts-certificate-error/625834#625834).

I recently faced the same problem and solved it by changing line 496 (may be different in your version) in C:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\getnonfreefonts\getnonfreefonts.pl from

```
system ("$WGET", "$getfont_url") == 0
```

to

```
system ("$WGET", "$getfont_url","--no-check-certificate") == 0
```

Of course this is a security risk because you are not verifying the SSL certificate but it provided the quick-fix I needed.

Comment: This takes effect. Awesome

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution to that problem is to change the source code of the script. Just search for `~kotucha` within the file (`C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\getnonfreefonts\getnonfreefonts.pl`, should yield 1 hit) and then change `https` to `http`.

Although that of course lessens the security on transport, it will at least get the script to proceed. And that is what was important to me (in March 2017, TL2016 on Windows). As @egreg pointed out for him it was not necessary, so probably it also depends on your computer.

Comment: You should at least mention the security implications. Especially given that there is no reason to do this according to egreg's comment above. So you are recommending less security for no benefit.

Comment: @cfr For me there was a reason, because I did get the same error as the OP. That was the easiest fix I could find (given that I was not able to clearly identify the `wget` line to pass `--no-check-certificate`).

Comment: Where do `C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\getnonfreefonts\getnonfreefonts.pl` is in Linux?

Comment: @Jh0an1Uzca73gu1 That's actually not easy to answer. Most Linux distributions don't install it. Have a look at https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/ for details.

Comment: @TeXnician: At last step, I got:
`sudo getnonfreefonts --sys
--2020-12-30 06:06:39--  https://www.tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.pl
Cargado certificado CA '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolviendo www.tug.org (www.tug.org)... 94.23.251.76
Conectando con www.tug.org (www.tug.org)[94.23.251.76]:443... conectado.
ERROR: El certificado de “www.tug.org” no es confiable.
ERROR: The certificate of “www.tug.org” doesn't have a known issuer.
! Error: Can't execute wget.`

Comment: @Jh0an1Uzca73gu1Do `which getnonfreefonts` and edit the file as given in the answer.