# getnonfreefonts Certificate error

Tags: fonts, texlive, scripts

My question has been asked before, but the answer does not work for me: [TeXLive getnonfreefonts-sys error: untrusted certificate from tug.org](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337941/texlive-getnonfreefonts-sys-error-untrusted-certificate-from-tug-org)

The script getnonfreefonts is unable to install the fonts and I get:

`--2021-11-06 14:47:39-- https://www.tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.pl Resolving www.tug.org... 94.23.251.76 Connecting to www.tug.org|94.23.251.76|:443... connected. ERROR: The certificate of 'www.tug.org' is not trusted. ERROR: The certificate of 'www.tug.org' has expired. ! Error: Can't execute wget. C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 5:`

If I change https to http in the code of the script I get instead

`Connecting to www.tug.org|94.23.251.76|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found Location: https://tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.pl [following] --2021-11-06 17:55:04--  https://tug.org/~kotucha/getnonfreefonts/getfont.pl Resolving tug.org... 94.23.251.76 Connecting to tug.org|94.23.251.76|:443... connected. ERROR: The certificate of 'tug.org' is not trusted. ERROR: The certificate of 'tug.org' has expired. ! Error: Can't execute wget. C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 5:`

Is this a temporary and/or known problem?

Comment: see the longish (and not fully resolved) thread on the texlive list starting https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2021-November/047539.html

Comment: basically you need to update your local wget or curl it seems https://savannah.nongnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=10054

Answer (score 2):

I recently faced the same problem and solved it by changing line 496 (may be different in your version) in `C:\texlive\2020\texmf-dist\scripts\getnonfreefonts\getnonfreefonts.pl` from

`system ("$WGET", "$getfont_url") == 0`

to

`system ("$WGET", "$getfont_url","--no-check-certificate") == 0`

Of course this is a security risk because you are not verifying the SSL certificate but it provided the quick-fix I needed.